# ssh-add -l shows no key but agent forwarding is working

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I log in on the server with my public key
Agent forwarding should be enabled, Defaults:user env_keep += SSH_AUTH_SOCK is in the /etc/sudoers

This works at my setting at home (Ubuntu Mate 20.04 -> Ubuntu Server 18.04), but not at work ( Windows 7 (winssh term) -> windows jump-server -> sles 15 server)

when i use

```
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

i get something like

```
/tmp/ssh-AyHL6WclXl/agent.107234
```

But when i use ssh-add -l no key is shown (the agent has no identities).
How do i get the key from the $SSH_AUTH_SOCK to ssh-add ?